# Go 1.0.2 How to improve speed when compressing with zlib

Tags: go, zlib

I'm working on a little program with Go (v1.0.2). I'm trying to load lines into memory, which I can recall by index (the first column of a line).
To save space, I compress every line with zlib. Lines are grouped by blocks.

Items are loaded from a file. An item is represented by a line. This line has many properties separated by tabulation.

It's working just fine, but it's currently really slow. It took me almost 50 sec to just load a 40 Mb file! (Note that if I disable the "compress" part, it takes only 0.87 sec). I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't find what. Please note that I'm a beginner in this language.

Note: I'm stuck with Go 1.0.2 and can't update.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "gotwcc/mylib"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Block struct {
    data []byte
}

type Row struct {
    offset, len uint32
    block       *Block
}

type Cache struct {
    blocks          []Block
    indexes         map[string]*Row
    enable_compress bool
    maxRowGroup     uint
}

func (this *Cache) dump() {
    for key, value := range this.indexes {
        fmt.Printf("[%s] = \"%s\"\n", key, value.block)
    }
}

func (this *Cache) search(item_id string) string {
    row := this.indexes[item_id]
    if row == nil {
        return "(Not found)"
    }
    block := this.uncompress(row.block.data)
    slice := block[row.offset : row.offset+row.len]
    return string(slice)
}

func (this *Cache) compress(data []byte) []byte {
    if !this.enable_compress {
        return data
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := zlib.NewWriter(&b)
    w.Write(data)
    w.Close()
    return b.Bytes()
}

func (this *Cache) uncompress(data []byte) []byte {
    if !this.enable_compress {
        return data
    }

    var res bytes.Buffer
    b := bytes.NewReader(data)
    r, err := zlib.NewReader(b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    io.Copy(&res, r)

    r.Close()
    return res.Bytes()

}

func (this *Cache) loadFile(s string) {
    type TempRowBuf struct {
        item_id     []byte
        offset, len uint32
    }

    file, err := os.Open(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := mybufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(mybufio.ScanLines)

    var tmp_buf bytes.Buffer
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var tmp_list []TempRowBuf
    this.indexes = make(map[string]*Row)

    var offset uint32 = 0
    nb := this.maxRowGroup
    for scanner.Scan() {
        nb--
        tmp_buf.Reset()
        tmp_buf.Write(scanner.Bytes())
        line := tmp_buf.Bytes()
        item_id, _ := tmp_buf.ReadBytes('\t')
        item_id = item_id[0 : len(item_id)-1]
        size := uint32(len(line))
        buffer.Write(line)
        tmp_list = append(tmp_list, TempRowBuf{item_id, offset, size})
        offset += size
        if nb <= 0 {
            compressed := this.compress(buffer.Bytes())
            buff := make([]byte, len(compressed))
            copy(buff, compressed)
            var block *Block = &Block{buff}
            for _, tmp := range tmp_list {
                this.indexes[string(tmp.item_id)] = &Row{tmp.offset, tmp.len, block}
            }
            nb = this.maxRowGroup
            offset = 0
            tmp_list = nil
            buffer.Reset()
        }
    }
    if nb > 0 {
        compressed := this.compress(buffer.Bytes())
        buff := make([]byte, len(compressed))
        copy(buff, compressed)
        var block *Block = &Block{buff}
        for _, tmp := range tmp_list {
            this.indexes[string(tmp.item_id)] = &Row{tmp.offset, tmp.len, block}
        }
    }
}

func wsCacheHandler(cache *Cache, writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    var value map[string]string = make(map[string]string)

    item_id := request.FormValue("item_id")
    value["item_id"] = item_id
    value["raw"] = cache.search(item_id)
    jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(value)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(writer, "%s", string(jsonResp))
    }
}

func main() {
    filename := flag.String("data", "default.txt", "The data filename")
    no_http := flag.Bool("no-http", false, "Do not start an http server")
    dumpMap := flag.Bool("dump", false, "If we should dump the map to stdout")
    noCompression := flag.Bool("no-compress", false, "Disable compression")
    maxRowGroup := flag.Uint("max-row-group", 100, "How much line to group when doing compression")

    flag.Parse()
    var cache Cache
    cache.enable_compress = !*noCompression
    cache.maxRowGroup = *maxRowGroup

    cache.loadFile(*filename)

    if *dumpMap {
        cache.dump()
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100001"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100002"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100003"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100004"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100005"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100006"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100007"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100008"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100009"))
        fmt.Println(cache.search("100010"))

    }

    if !*no_http {
        http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
            wsCacheHandler(&cache, writer, request)
        })
        fmt.Println("Cache loaded, now listening on port 8585...")
        http.ListenAndServe(":8585", nil)
    }
}
```

This is the test file I use (I'm not pasting the 40 Mo file here :p):

data.txt:

```
100001  bar
100002  foo
100003  bob
100004  nuts
100005  gogopowran
100006  green
100007  test
100008  alongwordwithlotofletters
100009  
100010  space space space
```

I launch my application like this:

```
time ./mybin -data=data.txt -no-http -no-compress => ok (0.6 sec to load)
time ./mybin -data=data.txt -no-http --max_row_group=100 => slow (12.1 sec to load)
time ./mybin -data=data.txt -no-http --max_row_group=1000 => still slow (10.9 sec to load)
time ./mybin -data=data.txt -no-http --max_row_group=10000 => still slow (10.6 sec to load)
```

Edit: Apply go fmt on the code. Add an option to choose the size of the packing. Test 3 different sizes.

Comment: Your code looks fine really, that version of Go is extremely old so might not have assembly enabled for gzip, why can't you upgrade?

Comment: Go doesn't use zlib. It has its own gzip compressor / decompressor. There have been vast speed improvements in the last few revisions of the Go standard library, perhaps you should update.

Comment: If you are stuck, you could take the go 1.3 `compression.zlib` module source code and embed it in your code.

Comment: @Marc: I approved your edit, but just as a note, the 'Mo' abbreviation for data size wasn't a typo. Rather, in French and possibly other languages, it's the abbreviation for English's "megabyte". The translation is "mega-octet". There are similar abbreviations for other scaled units.

Comment: @Novelocrat Thanks, it's in french actually, I thought it would be better if it was in English, since it's the language used on the site.

Comment: I'm not fluent in english, and yes it should be 40Mb (Novelocrat is right, Mo is in French). I will try to get compression.zlib.

Comment: Using compression.zlib from 1.3, doesn't help me. Has dependencies itself. I give this code to someone with go 1.2, and he has the same issue. In "compress" and "uncompress" function, I create a new buffer + a new zlib.Reader/Writer at every call, could it be the issue ?

Comment: https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/vitess/go/cgzip calls out to the C gzip library; https://code.google.com/p/snappy-go/ implements Snappy, a faster algorithm ideal for stuff like in-memory compression. I'm not at all sure I've puzzled out what all's going on in your program, and these may not actually help you. If you aren't currently experiencing pain caching plain blocks, compression may create more problems than it solves. :)

Comment: Related to "I don't know what all is going on": as of last year the built-in `compress/gzip` got ~38 Mo/s on a test system (https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2726), so I wonder if you're suffering from overhead due to many small blocks or something like that. Smaller blocks will also tend not to compress as well--larger blocks have more repetitions that can be compressed out, and let gzip-like packers 'learn' byte probabilities better.

Comment: Finally, the Go folks encourage you to use the `go fmt` command and a context-specific receiver name (e.g., `(c *Cache)` not `(this *Cache)`). Check out http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Answer (score -1):

Compressing each line individually is just going to be very slow, and provide relatively inefficient compression to boot.

Is there a reason you're not simply compressing the entire file? Or at least one "block" at a time?

Comment: I'm compressing a block, not a line (that's the purpose of the "Block" which is the concatenation of N lines). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The block appears to be 2 lines in the above which looks like it could be the bottleneck.  What happens if you set `MAX_ROW_GROUP` bigger? Creating and finalizing Zlib is expensive...

Comment: It's just a simplified test. The real test has a 40Mb file, and the MAX_ROW_GROUP value is 100. And that's really slow :(

Comment: Try making it bigger and time the difference.  If it makes no difference you'll know to look elsewhere.

Comment: I just edited my questions, adding an option to choose the size of the packing. I test with 100, 1000 and 10k, slow with every values :(.